# How to pass a collection or array from blade file to controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

`$cartItems` contains all the rows of products from database and I am using this inside a blade file.

I want to pass this `$cartItems` back to a controller from this blade file

Note: **`$cartItems`** is from `index()` function in a controller like below.

```php
$cartItems = DB::table('products')->whereIn('id', $cartItemsArray)->get();
return view('cart.index', compact('cartItems')
```

Below is my code.

`index.blade.php`

```php
<a href="{{route('cart.checkout',$cartItems)}}" class="site-btn">Proceed to checkout</a>
```

`web.php`

```php
Route::get('/cart/checkout/{cartItems}', 'CartController@checkout')->name('cart.checkout')->middleware('auth');
```

`CartController.php`

```php
public function checkout($cartItems)
{
   dd($cartItems);
   return view('cart.checkout');
}
```

The error I am getting is,

> Missing required parameters for [Route: cart.checkout] [URI: cart/checkout/{cartItems}]. (View: E:\github\LARAVEL\Deal-Ocean\resources\views\cart\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a form to send data back to server

Update your route from `get` to `post`

```
Route::post('/cart/checkout', 'CartController@checkout')->name('cart.checkout')->middleware('auth');
```

Use a form to post data to server. You can pass any additional data along with the request as well.

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/checkout">
@foreach($cartItems as $item)
    <input name="cartItems[]" value="{{ $item->id }}"
@endforeach
<button class="site-btn">Proceed to checkout</button>
</form>
```

And in your controller use `Request` to access data

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    $cartItems = DB::table('products')->whereIn('id', $request->get($cartItems))->get();
   dd($cartItems);
   return view('cart.checkout');
}
```

---

If you want to proceed with the get request you should be able to do as follow

As `$cartItems` is a collection of products. So you can send the product ids and query the products using the ids from request.

```
<a href="{{ route('cart.checkout', ['cartItems' => $cartItems->pluck('id')->toArray()]) }}" 
    class="site-btn">Proceed to checkout</a>
```

Update controller

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    $cartItems = DB::table('products')->whereIn('id', $request->get($cartItems))->get();
   dd($cartItems);
   return view('cart.checkout');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use the same code logic of the **index()** method in the **checkout** method in the
CartController.

the checkout method will look like this:

```
   $cartItems = DB::table('products')->whereIn('id', $cartItemsArray)->get();
   return view('cart.checkout', compact('cartItems');
```

Comment: I have cart page in index.blade. I have products with number of occurance in that page. and calculated the total price. Now I had to send the `$cartItems` and `$totalPrice` to `CartController`.  and use it for further calculation. But if its not possible to send the data directly. then I have to query again in `checkout method`. I can send normal `variable` but cant send the array